# How can I type the greater-than & less-than sign in HTML without it starting a new element?

Tags: html, tags, codepen

I'm using CodePen to take care of the first few projects on CodeCamp. For one of them I'm supposed to make a technical document and I decided to make it about starting an html file.

I want to type < or >in a code or paragraph tag but once I do it automatically assumes I'm making a new element and highlights everything. Is there a way around this?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp

Answer (score 4):

```html
<body>
  <p>
    this is a paragraph.  you can use like this &lt;some text&gt;
  </p>
</body>
```

you can use `&lt;` and `&gt;`

Comment: I was having issues with a python string containing double of those less/greater characters. Fixed it this way:

txt = txt.replace('<', '&lt').replace('>', '&gt')

Stuff like xxx<<yy>>xxx is now printing correctly in web applications.